# Eclipse BIRT scripted data source blank records listed

Tags: eclipse, birt

I've integrated Eclipse BIRT with maximo report libraries to create a custom report and I made my open and fetch methods. However, when I preview my results it says 500 records displayed (more results available) but all the columns are blank. Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Did you also define output columns for the dataset with the same names as in your fetch script? It depends a bit on your report, but I don't think it's related to the dataset being limited. You can change that property in prefences->Report Design->Preview->Data